# Boot Screen w/ GNU GRUB Purple and Black Overlay After Installing Nvidia Drivers

Tags: grub2, nvidia, 17.04

After installing the latest nvidia drivers on my Ubuntu 17.10, my boot screen has started to have this black on purple overlay:

[image: Photo of Issue]

I'm on a GTX 770 Video Card. I've reinstalled the drivers (v390) while also downgrading to v384 to no avail:

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia-*'
sudo apt install nvidia-390
```

I also grabbed the boot-repair tool to reinstall the GRUB and boot settings in case but that has also had no effect:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
```

Finally, I tried following these instructions which also had no effect:
https://blog.countableset.com/2017/06/01/ubuntu-1704-install-nvidia-drivers/

Would love any thoughts around this if anyone else has seen anything like this, otherwise, happy to file a bug somewhere if anyone can provide best details on where and what logs would be valuable.

Thanks

Comment: I recently saw something like this on an old laptop with NVIDIA Geoforce 8300 graphics.  I was using the legacy nvidia-304 driver which worked well, but it got broken by a kernel update and apparently isn't going to be fixed.  I tried running nvidia-340 instead and I often got a screen like your picture, and my filesystem kept getting corrupted.  I gave up and installed the noveau driver, and it works OK. The old nvidia-304 managed the power level much better though, the laptop gets really hot with noveau.

Comment: I have this same issue after a clean ubuntu 17.10 install and updating to the recent nvidia drivers :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [regression](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1752767) introduced recently (GRUB version `2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.2`). This is fixed now and the fix has been released. Update your system by running

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

which should update GRUB to version `2.02~beta3-4ubuntu7.3` and your GRUB screen should look like before now.